# How should a team push their changes to git master?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git

In the past we (a coworker and I) would push our changes directly to master. And then inform each other that changes need to be pulled.

A new coworker suggests forking the git repo and when he makes changes. He does a pull request. I would still be on the master repo and accept the request for the pull.

Which is the traditional / common approach when working together as a team? Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on if you want to have one central repository or not. Many organizations have been using and continue using a central repository when they switch to git. It also depends on access, trust and how many developers you are. If you are only a few devs and you all trust each other, I'd go with a central bare repository that everyone pushes to and pulls from. Keep it simple.

If you are 100 developers and perhaps also external developers that you don't trust using your central repo and want to restrict access for some other reasons then pull requests might be the solution.

The important thing is to look at what kind of workflow YOU want and keep in mind that git will not get in your way and will let you decide that for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way is to fork-pull, i.e. the Linus-fork of the Linux kernel is the official line. The difference to your current approach is the amount of control you are having over the changes. If you don't need this control or if you can't check the changes anyway because you don't have the time to do so, theres no advantage in pulling manually. Git does handle resets/deletes very good and you can always go back in history.

Answer (score 0):

Forking a git repo is a much better approach when working in a team as it makes sure your repo and code never hit an inconsistent stage. However this practice is not very common in the world. Most teams have made it a tradition where everybody is working on the same branch at the same time, this is a bit dangerous but can be made efficient by adding an email alert sending functionality in the post-receive hook of the repo so that the other team-mates can pull the changes as soon as they get an email alert.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would say there are two main workflows:

1. As Magnus said everybody is pushing to the "blessed" bare repo, while working on the local clones of it.
2. More restricted work flow may suggest limited number of people having push access to the blessed repo and all other contributors are either sending pull requests or if the pull is technically difficult they provide patches. But they are pulling from blessed repo to keep their repos in sync. This workflow implies code review by "lieutenants" before the change goes to the blessed repo